# In python, how can I begin a program at a given system time?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, time, wait

In python I've been using sleep to execute a looping piece of code every hour, minute, or day. Problem is the script takes about 1-3 seconds to run. How can I make sure that the script begins when the next minute arrives, for example I start the script and there are 20 seconds left in the current minute.

Using time I get these results, notice I lose precision with each second:

```
Waiting for next half min.
2013-09-14 15:46:53.850068
307
Waiting for next half min.
2013-09-14 15:47:24.158642
307
Waiting for next half min.
2013-09-14 15:47:54.717070
302
Waiting for next half min.
2013-09-14 15:48:25.296409
325
Waiting for next half min.
2013-09-14 15:48:55.506098
```

Comment: Show your Python code, or buy a more speedy hardware.

Comment: when you finish your current task, figure out how long until the next time you want to run, and then sleep for that long.

Comment: agree with @tcaswell, seems to be the most straightforward method.

Comment: cron job on Linux or scheduled task on Windows if you run script periodically every minute

Comment: @pxl I think thats the correct way also

Answer (score 1):

I assume that imprecision that you're getting with your timing is due to unpredictable python interpreter start-up times.

If you need to make sure your actual *code* starts executing at the exact time, you can do the following:

- make your script to be ran a bit earlier than you need
- in the script:

  ```
  import time
  import datetime

  schedule_time = ... # parse sys.argv or whatevs

  # this will wait exactly as much time as it is left before the schedule
  time.sleep((schedule_time - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds())
  # ... your code
  ```

Comment: No my problem really has to do with the function taking time because it's gathering data, which takes 0 to 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out the appropriate sleep time after each time your code does work.  The following code does this, and also tries to catch up in the event that a work task takes longer than the delay interval.

```
import time

# Get the start time, also the time of the next (first) iteration
lTimeNext = time.time()

# Set up the delay time
lDelay = 30

# Loop, doing work
while True:

  # Do Work
  print "Working!"

  # Work out when to do the next work item
  lTimeNext += lDelay

  # Sleep until the next work is required
  lSleepTime = lTimeNext - time.time()
  if lSleepTime > 0:
    time.sleep(lSleepTime)
```